# Adding in captions for subfigures leads to completely separate figures rather than labels like (a) or (b)

Tags: subcaption

I have a figure in my LaTeX file with two subfigures. I want to add a label to each subfigure like (a) and (b) while maintaining an overall description of the figure below.

The code that I have is like this:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[trim={0, 50, 0, 0}, width=0.5\textwidth]{figures/plot1.pdf}
        \caption{Caption 1} \label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[trim={0, 50, 0, 0}, width=0.5\textwidth]{figures/plot2.pdf}
        \caption{Caption 2} \label{fig:2a}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Something.}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure*}
```

However, this produces the following:
[image]

As you can see, this is not at all what I want. How should I go about maintaining the two subfigures side by side while adding labels beneath them? Thanks.

Comment: You also probably want [clip=true].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the correct labeling for subfigures, you have to use `\subcaption` instead of the regular `\caption`.

Also, the `subfigure` environment takes another obligatory argument for its width. If you set that to `.5\textwidth` or less for both figures, they should appear side by side.